# Is using %zu correct syntax in a printf format string as shown in some C code found on Wikipedia?

Tags: c, printf, sizeof

I just found this code on Wikipedia.
Link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sizeof#Use

The code:

```
/* the following code illustrates the use of sizeof 
 * with variables and expressions (no parentheses needed),
 * and with type names (parentheses needed)
 */

char c;

printf("%zu,%zu", sizeof c, sizeof(int));
```

It states that: "The z prefix should be used to print it, because the actual size can differ on each architecture."

I tried it on my compiler, but it gives the following result:

```
zu,zu
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes that syntax is correct (at least for C99).  Looks like your compiler isn't set up to handle it though. Just take out the `z` and you'll probably be fine.  To be correct, make sure your `printf` format specifiers match the size of the types.  Turning on all the warnings your compiler will give you probably helps out in that respect.

Your quotation:

> The z prefix should be used to print it, because the actual size can differ on each architecture

is referring to the fact that `size_t` (which is the type returned by the `sizeof` operator) can vary from architecture to architecture.  The `z` is intended to make your code more portable.  However, if your compiler doesn't support it, that's not going to work out.  Just fiddle with combinations of `%u`, `%lu`, etc. until you get the output making sense.

Comment: You can use `%lu` and explicitly cast the `sizeof` value to `unsigned long` - as long as you know that the size of the object is less than 4GB you know then that it will definitely be reported correctly.

Answer (score 6):

The `z` length modifier was added to C in the C99 standard; you might have a compiler that doesn't support [C99](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99).

If your C compiler doesn't support that, you can probably treat the sizes as unsigned long:

```
printf("%lu,%lu", (unsigned long)sizeof c, (unsigned long)sizeof(int));
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but it only works on [C99](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99)-compliant compilers.  From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf#printf_format_placeholders):

> z: For integer types, causes printf to expect a size_t  sized integer argument.

Answer (score 1):

Did you tell your compiler that you want it thinking with a C99 brain? There is probably a switch to do that. For instance, `-std=c99` for gcc.

If your compiler does not support it, but you know others will, you can do a `PRId64` style work around (disclaimer - PSEUDO CODE AHEAD ..):

```
#ifdef __SOME_KNOWN_C99_COMPILER
#define PORTUNSIGNED "zu"
#else
#define PORTUNSIGNED "u"
#endif

printf("%-11" PORTUNSIGNED " ways to skin a cat\n");
```

Its probably better to get a compiler that has functional support for c99, however.

Comment: The preprocessor is not evil.

Comment: @George - I'm not saying its evil, I'm just saying that some stop actually using it and start improvising with it, which leads to interesting things that other people eventually have to maintain :)

Answer (score 0):

I've made a test using gcc 4.0. It works with `-std=c99`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the `-std=c99` suggestion @Tim Post and @pcent.
For novices like me, a bit more detail:
I'm using Windows and ming_w32_gcc.
When I compiled my code using:

```
gcc -Werror -Wall q3.c
```

I got the error message "unknown conversion type character 'z' in format"
But when I added -std=c99 on the end it worked fine:

```
gcc -Werror -Wall q3.c -std=c99
```

Comment: This just affirms an existing answer. Please upvote instead of posting 'thank you' answers.